# Formatting date returned from Parse.com

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am running a query on a Parse.com object and returning the `updatedAt` and wish to display this as a nicely formatted date for my users on my Ionic App.

It currently displays like this:

`2015-03-27T21:38:22.606Z`

I would like this to display as:

`27-03-2015 at 21:38`

an example of the object that I am using to display this data is below:

```
 var programmeData = {   
    programmeTitle : object.get('prescribedProgrammeTitle'),
    id : object.id,
    exerciseData : object.get('exerciseData'),
    prescribedDate :object.updatedAt,
 };
```

I can run formatting in my controller / service or view - advice on how to do this correctly would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the AngularJS [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

To format it directly in html you would need to put programmeData on the $scope:

```
{{ programmeData | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy at HH:mm' }}
```

Or in your controller you could inject $filter to format it:

```
$filter('date')(programmeData, 'dd-MM-yyyy at HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use http://momentjs.com/

There are many ways to parse the date using this library.